# Create a flow that updates fields on Account after Approval

Tags: visual-workflow, recordtriggeredflow

I nedd your help please.
I have to create a flow that whenever an object called "anyname" changes it’s approval status to Approved(following an approval process), will update the fields of it’s corresponding account with the new values.

Many Thanks!!!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE community. Can you please help to Edit your question and update what you're have tried so far & where you're struck on your given requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you can follow to create a flow that updates the fields of an account when an object record's approval status is changed to "Approved":

1)Create a new flow in Salesforce Setup by navigating to Setup > Flows > New Flow.

2)Set the flow type to "Record-Triggered Flow".

3)Choose the "anyname" object as the primary object for the flow.

4)Add a new "Get Records" element to the flow, and configure it to retrieve the account record that corresponds to the "anyname" record using a Lookup field on the "anyname" object that references the account.

5)Add a "Decision" element to the flow, and configure it to check whether the "anyname" record's approval status is "Approved".

6)If the approval status is "Approved", add an "Update Records" element to the flow, and configure it to update the corresponding account record with the new values from the "anyname" record. You can use the "Update Records" element's Field Reference feature to set the account fields to the values from the "anyname" record fields.

7)Save the flow and activate it.

Note: You'll need to ensure that the lookup field on the "anyname" object that references the account is populated correctly, and that the account record exists and is accessible by the running user.